# Unknown host 'downloads.gradle.org' When new project is created in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

On creating new project I get Error:

[image: Now]

> Failed to sync Gradle project
> Unknown host 'downloads.gradle.org'
>     Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

Before I was not getting any error and also my project structure in android was different there was only "app" folder which contained 3 folders "manifest" "java" and "res" as:

[image: Before]

I have searched on google but can't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: Are you using a proxy of some sort? EDIT: If you go to File --> Settings --> HTTP Proxy  and click "Test Connection", what happens?

Comment: I agree with ahjohnston25.  When building Android apps using Gradle, there is lots of internet access.  This sounds like Android Studio is just not able to get out to the internet.

Comment: The reason that you are seeing a different directory structure is that you've changed how Android Studio shows the structure.  Click on the little down arrow next to the "Android" text (underneath "My First App" in the upper left) and select "Project".

Answer (score 5):

Goto local disk(c) -> users -> username -> .gradle -> delete everything from that folder and restart android studio

Answer (score -2):

Go to.. Settings ->
Configuration — > HTTP Proxy —> and select — > auto-detect proxy settings — > Click — OK